# Qt Creator: how to set debug or release mode

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am making a C++ project in Qt Creator, using cmake and my own CMakeLists.txt file. How do I specify whether I want to build in debug or release mode? Is this something I set in Qt Creator, or in CMakeLists?

Answer (score 8):

In Qt creator, you will find the option towards the left bottom, just above the run button.

Build configurations for Debug and Release builds can be accessed by clicking on "Projects" in the left toolbar while ur project is open.

Comment: These options are not present for a CMake project.

Answer (score 4):

You should set the CMake param "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE" to "Release" or "Debug", depending on if you want to build in release or debug mode.

You will not be able to debug your project without setting that param to "Debug", because Qt will not find the debugging symbols.